# Como capturar (GET) vários valores enviados na mesma variável (PHP)?

Tags: php, variáveis, post, get

Após uma query, estou enviando diferentes valores através da mesma variável (através de um input):

```html
 <input type="hidden" id="sku" name="sku" value="<?= $reg->sku ?>">
```

Dessa forma, minha URL fica da seguinte maneira:

```
http://localhost/admin/anuncios/relatorios/exportado_confirm.php?sku=BL001_BA307&sku=BL001_BA308&sku=BL001_BA667&sku=BL001_BA668&sku=BL001_BA672&sku=BL003_BA309&sku=BL005_BA27&sku=BL166_BA7&sku=BL166_BA8&sku=BL178_BA310&sku=BL184_BA1&sku=BL184_BA4&sku=BL184_BA669&sku=BL202_BA5
```

Mas eu não consigo depois capturar todas os "sku" enviados através do `$sku = $_GET['sku']);`

Pois quando mando rodar o seguinte `UPDATE`:  `$sql = "update anuncios set exportado = '1' where sku = '{$sku}'";`

Ele só consegue capturar o último valor enviado na variável "sku" e rodar o UPDATE nesse último "sku" listado na URL.

Queria poder capturar todos os valores, e esse `UPDATE` rodasse (while) enquanto existisse algum valor na variável sku. Alguém tem alguma sugestão para me ajudar?

Obs: Na verdade estou fazendo tudo por POST, apenas coloquei por GET para ficar visível os valores enviados na mesma variável.

Comment: Tente definir o campo `input` com `name="sku[]"`, adicionando os colchetes. Assim, acredito que `$_GET["sku"]` será um *array*, mas lembre-se de convertê-lo devidamente para *string* antes de utilizar na consulta SQL.

Comment: Sabe usar o explode? Pode ser que ajuda. $skus = explode('&', $_GET); depois disso basta dar um count(skus) para saber o número de valores retornados

Comment: meio confusão isso ai, começa com get e no final vira post e é só um input, se é só um input para que colchete no name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A estrutura oficial da URL é definida pela [RFC 2986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), tendo a sessão 3.4 abordando a definição da *query* e mesmo nela não há nenhuma forma "oficial" para se passar múltiplos valores para um mesmo parâmetro. Sendo a *query* um valor opaco - isto é, o seu real significado depende da implementação que irá analisar a URL, a forma para se passar múltiplos valores irá variar.

No PHP, oficialmente utiliza-se os colchetes após o nome do campo:

```
<input type="hidden" id="sku" name="sku[]" value="BL001_BA307"> 
<input type="hidden" id="sku" name="sku[]" value="BL001_BA308"> 
<input type="hidden" id="sku" name="sku[]" value="BL001_BA667">
```

Isso gerará uma URL parecida com:

```
//localhost?sku[]=BL001_BA307&sku[]=BL001_BA308&sku[]=BL001_BA667
```

E o PHP, ao analisá-la, irá gerar um *array* com tais informações:

```
var_dump($_GET["sku"]);

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "BL001_BA307"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "BL001_BA308"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "BL001_BA667"
}
```

Assim você poderá utilizar todas as informações junto ao SQL, lembrando que o mesmo deverá ser devidamente convertido para *string* antes de utilizá-lo na consulta SQL.

Essa técnica funcionará tanto para requisições GET quanto POST. A única diferença, de fato, entre elas será a forma que os valores serão passados via requisição HTTP: no GET é via URL e no POST é via corpo da requisição.

Como na consulta SQL, o resultado pretendido é algo como:

```
select ... where sku in ("BL001_BA307", "BL001_BA308", "BL001_BA667");
```

O que você pode fazer é utilizar o `implode` do PHP:

```
$sku = implode(",", array_map(function ($item) {
    return sprintf('"%s"', $item);
}, $_GET["sku"]));

// $sku = '"BL001_BA307", "BL001_BA308", "BL001_BA667"';
```

E no SQL:

```
select ... where sku in ({$sku});
```

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo sem saber o código que trata essas URLs é difícil dizer, mas a presença dos colchetes faz o PHP entender que trata-se de um mesmo campo, convertendo assim para um *array* em `$_GET["sku"]` (ou POST). Sem os colchetes, o PHP pegará apenas o último valor.

Comment: sei disso, só não estou entendendo o porque dos colchetes se é só um input, ou talvez eu esteja enganado e devem ser vários inputs ..

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo pela estrutura do código é possível assertar que são múltiplos campos, pois `$reg` tende a ser um objeto que está iterando os resultados de uma consulta ao banco de dados. Ou seja, existirá um campo para cada registro. O próprio autor começa dizendo "após uma *query*..." :D

Comment: valeu Anderson, meu mal é que levo o português ao pé da letra :)